# Why high Reynolds number "implies" high airspeed?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, viscosity

Reynold number is ratio between (density,length,velocity) and viscosity, one Re number can has countless possiblities of different values of density,length,velocity and viscosity.

I dont understand why then when talk about Re number and drag coefficent,increasing Re "means increasing airspeed"?We can increase for example  density or reduce viscosity and Re number will rise etc etc...

So why would Re=1 000 000 has faster airspeed than Re=1000?

I dont  know at this graph what is "honey" and what is "air",if I can allways manipulate with all 4 parameters in Re formula.

I can get Re<10  with air too,if speed is very slow or length is very small..So I dont know if am working with air or honey or is airspeed very slow or viscosity is very high.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5xwk24oblM&ab_channel=GuyRiefler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, there are many ways to change the Reynolds number of a flow.

However, most of them are not practical. When looking at real-world examples, the size of the article is mostly given (from an existing airplane, say) and the easiest way to change its Reynolds number is to change speed. Another way is to change density by climbing or descending, but that takes more effort. Another way would be to change viscosity by changing air temperature, but that becomes unpractical very soon. You cannot heat air sufficiently to cut Re in half without suffering unacceptable consequences, and changing density is coupled to a change in temperature over much of the atmosphere in which airplanes fly.

The Reynolds number is meant to aid the comparison of flow regimes, say between windtunnel models and real airplanes or between two different airplanes. In order to adjust the Reynolds number of one to match the other, a change in speed is the easiest way to achieve that goal. Just look at what has to be done to match both Reynolds and Mach numbers in windtunnels to the original airplane: [Cryogenic windtunnels](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/79806/what-are-some-specific-benefits-of-cryogenic-wind-tunnels/79814?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C16.0708#79814) need to change pressure, temperature and the gas itself to achieve that goal. The cost and complexity of doing this is immense.

Comment: But at my graph  at post,how do I know what is speed behind for example Re= 1 000 000 if I dont know density,length of sphere and viscosity? My assumption is they keep density,length and viscosity during test or calculation for this graph the same,so rise Re means rise in speed,but I  still dont know what is magnitude of speed behind each Re numbers.

Comment: @ebv821 A good test report will list all parameters. Most windtunnel tests will use air at atmospheric pressure at the location and ambient temperature, so it is fair to assume that any change in Re is from a change in speed. With CFD, no such assumptions can be made as parameters can be completely arbitrary.

Comment: **Most windtunnel tests will use air at atmospheric pressure at the location and ambient temperature,** If do that ,they will not have same Re number as full size plane,how then they get correct results?

Comment: @EBV821 By correcting for the differences. No windtunnel reading can be taken at face value but needs to have [correction factors](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/do-software-simulations-and-wind-tunnel-tests-accurately-predict-cd-and-cl-in-re/22865#22865) applied.